Is the getReferenceById repository method really lazy loading and how to test it throws an exception?
I understand the getReferenceById repository method is lazy loading the entity.
So I have the following service:
@Service
public class PostService {

    public Post getReferenceById(Long id) {
        return postRepository.getReferenceById(id);
    }

And I expect the following test case to throw an exception:
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
class PostServiceTest {
    // The getReferenceById repository method is lazy loading
    // and not accessing the entity inside of the transaction scope
    // and accessing the entity outside of the transaction scope
    // should trigger a LazyInitializationException exception
    @Test
    void whenGetUsedOutsideOfServiceThenThrowException() {
        Post post = postService.getReferenceById(EXISTING_ID);
        assertThatExceptionOfType(LazyInitializationException.class)
        .isThrownBy(post::getId);
    }

But it does not. Instead it returns the loaded entity.
My application.yml properties file prevents SpringBoot from keeping the Hibernate session opened after the transaction has closed:
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false

I'm on SpringBoot 3.3.0

Have you tried with a different method? If I recall correctly, the call to get the identifier is handled by the proxy without loading the entity.

@RobbyCornelissen You are right ! I just did some debugging on this and tried with additional accessors, like post.getBody(); and post.getIsbn(); and these two did trigger the exception being thrown. Indeed, the getId() is fetching the id from the proxy object itself, whereas all other properties are attempted to be fetched from the entity.

Running the debugger I could see all the properties, including the id property, had a null value, after calling the service method:
Post post = postService.getReferenceById(EXISTING_ID);

So I wrongly assumed that calling the getId() method would attempt to get the id property from the entity object and thus trigger an exception.
But, in fact, as pointed out above by a commenter, the getId() method gets the id property from the proxy object thus not triggering an exception.
All other accessors attempt to get their values from the entity object. And using them outside of a transaction on a not yet loaded entity, does trigger the expected exception.
